# MVC kendo grid display full date in edit mode in IE only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

when i want to edit date inside kendo grid don't display datetime picker in IE, while its working fine in chrome

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.Person>().Name("people")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(m => m.PersonID);
        model.Field(f => f.Name);
    })
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetPeople", "Home").Data("extraData"))
        .Update(up => up.Action("UpdatePerson", "Home"))

)
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.PersonID);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
    columns.Bound(k => k.BirthDate).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}");
   columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Edit());
})
.Events(ev => ev.DataBound("db"))
)
```

[see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8tMS.png)
  i use ASP.NET5 RC1 MVC

```
 <script src="~/lib/kendo-ui/js/cultures/kendo.culture.es-MX.min.js"></script>
<script>
    kendo.culture("es-MX");
</script>
```

the model .....

```
  public class Person
  {
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public Nullable<DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution :)
i add in shared folder-> EditorTemplates -> the file DateTime.cshtml

```
@model DateTime?
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(m => m))
```